# Kendo UI TreeList - adding row

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treelist, createchildcontrols

I have some troubles when adding row in a treelist Kendo, espessially Add Child Row.  I click Add Child Row, then put data into fields, and after clicking OK, row disappeared. So i can't add CHILD row.

I took sample from official site. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#configuration-messages.commands.create . Use Chrome. 
Does it is telerik kendo developing error? How to use adding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the TreeList [DataSource transport configured for CRUD operations](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud). If you use the [TreeList editing demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/editing) as a starting point, the scenario will work:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EKoCi

Probably the documentation should mention the above explicitly to prevent confusion.

Comment: Good. Please consider marking my response as the answer.